# Pragmatic way to push configuration changes to servers

Tags: java, database, architecture

The system contains an admin console and a cluster of working servers. Application state is stored in the database. From admin console user can add new jobs, monitor running jobs etc. Working servers fetch the job from db and process it.

Now, some configuration is stored in database, too. Configurations are also loaded on each working server and most of it is cached, as configuration is not changed frequently.

Admin is able to change configuration (from admin console). The change is stored in database. What would be the best way to push changes to working servers?

My ideas so far:

1. add triggers on configuration table on update/delete/insert and update the timestamp in some aux table. Each working server before accessing the cache checks this aux table for change.
   CONS: Still accessing db.
2. send request from admin console to all working server that configuration is changed and that has to be read from db on next call.
   CONS: introduces http communication between admin and servers - new layer that didn't exist so far - and its questionable how reliable that would be.

Any experience on this subject?

Comment: Why can't the admin console initiate updating?

Comment: Its installed on separate computer instance, out of cluster of working computers. So basically the idea #2 is where admin console initiate the updating. Will clarify my question.

Comment: Make the database close all connections and tell the servers to reconfigure when that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First approach seems more like a quick hack. Checking aux table timestamps almost defeats the purpose of a cache.

Second option seems to be the good one. This could be implemented as a simple task in their task queue to update their own configuration caches.

The main issue changing configuration of multiple services is their dependencies.

If parent service would start running with incompatible configuration to it's child services you might get a crash or undefined behaviour. To avoid this the synchronisation must be implemented.

One way is let parent service to update it's configuration and then issue configuration update commands to child services. After all child services are updated, parent would resume processing. Advantage of this approach would be that a simple management console could instruct only parent services about the configuration changes.

Other way is let management console handle dependent services. It would send a command to parent services to pause execution, update config and wait for resume command. In a mean time it would update all child services and instruct parents to resume. This way service dependencies would be more flexible and their configuration would be decoupled from their implementation. This would require a more advanced administration tool.

Comment: Thanx for pointing out the sync problem, i overlooked it. I will wait a bit more, bit this seems to be a solution i'm looking for (synchronized parent->child notification). I am afraid that the other way (pausing), might not be good, as it might be expensive (from business view).

Comment: @IgorSpasic, if you update child services in parallel the pause should be a matter of milliseconds. Unless you are doing some realtime processing this should not be an issue at all. There is no other way to sync without waiting till all dependent services are updated.

Comment: Understood, just seems that pausing one parent is less expensive than pausing worker servers, as they already have many concurrent working sessions, doing some real time work. Thank you!